# Creating a ZIP file of an EAR with Maven

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm got a pretty simple question... I have a Maven 3 project set up like so:

Root POM project
 - EAR project: depends on the WAR project
 - WAR project

I'd like to use the assembly plug-in to make a ZIP file containing the exploded EAR (which contains the WAR).  Any suggestions on how I should do this?  Should I put the assembly configuration details in the root .pom or EAR .pom?

Thanks!
-Jon

Comment: What's the point of zipping an exploded EAR? A (non-exploded) EAR is a zip file.

Comment: It has to do with how we release our EAR's to the operations team.  They are in a ZIP that includes other files for operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a third project, say *earzip*, with a `dependency` on the `ear` project.  This project can have the necessary configuration (`assembly descriptor` and other `plugin` definitions as required) to explode the ear and zip it up again as suitable.  This will keep your parent pom clean, as well as not put multiple things in your ear pom.

Comment: @Raghuram Could you provide a more detailed example please? I'm aslo trying to take an EAR-file build by my EAR-module and put it into an zip-file but I always getting the error that I have to set at least one file.

Answer (score 0):

When I was looking for the way to run batch script from ant (~1 year ago) I found only the following solution:

1. In the pom that builds your parent project add [runant](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin
2. In the ant script (1) add target that [runs a batch script](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#batch-shell-execute) (if on Windows)
3. In the batch script (2) add archiving task.

No point to add zipping task to the pom that builds an EAR (IMHO). It should be parent pom task.

I hope that these threee would do the magic.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I'd like to package things up using what Maven has to offer, if possible (we're migrating from Ant and I'd like to see what Maven itself can do).